# ¿Cómo consumo este Web Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice

Tratando de aprender cómo funciona y el consumo de un *Web Service* he dado muchas vueltas y los ejemplos que encuentro no logro adaptarlos y hacerlos funcionar a lo que quiero.

Tengo el siguiente *Web Service* y no se muy bien cómo puedo hacer para consumirlo

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.mysite.com.co/WS/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class ServicioSUCIS : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public ServicioSUCIS()
    {
        //Elimine la marca de comentario de la línea siguiente si utiliza los componentes diseñados 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [SoapDocumentMethod (Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal)]

    public DataTable consultaIndividualSUCIS(int tipoId, int numId)
    {
        try
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT tipoCodigoEntidad,    Nombre,     estadoAutorizacion,     tipoIntermediario,  indicadorVinculado,     tipoIdEntidadVincula,   numIdEntidadVincula,    nombreEntidadVincula,   fechaVinculacion,   fechaDesvinculacion,    organismoAutorizado,    fechaIniAcreditacion,   fechaFinAcreditacion,   ramosAutorizados FROM Idoneidad_Funcionarios WHERE tipoId = @tipoId AND numId = @numId"))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipoid", tipoId);  // <-- Este es el parámetro de SQL que estás recibiendo cómo parámetro en tu método
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numId", numId);  // <-- Este es el parámetro de SQL que estás recibiendo cómo parámetro en tu método

                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            dt.TableName = "Idoneidad_Funcionarios";

                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            return dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Eso me arroja el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo tengo un poco perdido, pero prueba a añadir webreference, luego pones la ruta donde esta publicado el WS y ya te aparecera una nueva clase con los metodos que ofrece el WS

Comment: Entiendo que el servicio, cuando accedes a su url funciona correctamente, y tu pregunta tiene que ver con como consumirlo desde otra aplicación?

Comment: Así es @Pikoh tengo entendido que se usan 2 aplicaciones una para crearlo y la otra para probarlo, ¿cómo se realiza la otra de prueba?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución de @NeKSV sirve para webservices WCF y de ese tipo. Para los webservices de .net clasicos, debes hacer los siguiente:

- En el explorador de soluciones de la aplicación donde quieras consumir el webservices, pulsas con el boton derecho en `Referencias` y te aparecerá esta ventana:
  [image: [introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]]
- Aqui deberás pulsar en `Avanzadas...` en la parte inferior, y te aparecerá lo siguiente:

[image: [introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]]

- Como ves, en la parte inferior ya tienes la opción `Agregar referencia web...`. Pulsando te aparecerá la siguiente ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Aqui pegas tu URL y le das a `Agregar referencia` y ya tienes añadido el webservice.
- Por último, en tu código no tienes mas que crear una instancia de tu webservice, algo asi:

  ```
  tunombredereferencia.ServicioSUCIS ws = new tunombredereferencia.ServicioSUCIS();
  ws.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
  ws.PreAuthenticate = true;
  ws.ConsultaIndividualSUCIS(tipoID, numID);
  ```

Comment: Muchas gracias compa por tu tiempo y paciencia, estaba probando el método de NekSV y no me cuadraba, y de razón no me cuadraba, por lo que es clasico el webservice.
Entonces me puse a probar tu método y ese iba todo bien hasta que me arrojó error en:
[ ws.consultaIndividualSUCIS (tipoId, numId); ]
el nombre tipoId no existe en el contexto actual, esto lo agregue en el Default.cs

Comment: `tipoID` es un ejemplo que puse. Tu tendrás que mandar el parámetro que corresponda en la llamada a tu webservice, yo no se exactamente que parámetro recibe tu metodo `consultaIndividualSUCIS`

Comment: Hola Pikoh, `tipoId` es uno de los parámetros que tiene ese método, eso es lo que se me hace raro que no lo reconozca.

Comment: Claro, pero lo que tu tienes que pasarle es o el valor o una nueva variable. O bien `ws.ConsultaIndividualSUCIS(1, 1);` o bien `int tipoID=1;int numID=1;ws.ConsultaIndividualSUCIS(tipoID, numID);`

Comment: Ahhh ya comprendí, pues compa muchas gracias por su paciencia y explicarme esta cosa del WS! mil gracias!.

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar una referencia web a tu proyecto de visual studio debes:

- Clic derecho sobre Referencias (References)
- Pegar la URL del servicio que deseas consumir en la casilla "Address" y luego hacer clic en go, esto desencadena la busqueda de contratos en ese "Endpoint" y te mostrara todos los contratos disponibles.
- Selecciona el contrato que deseas y has clic en OK y listo.

Para acceder a los metodos debes incluir el namespace de tu contracto y crear un cliente para su consumo (var webserviceClient = new namespace.AutoGeneratedClient())