# Ejecutar web service con usuario y pass y retorna un json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net

necesito consumir un web service que retorna un json y no se que hacer pare recorrer el resultado ya que lo debo almacenar en uan tabla en la base de datos, me podrían ayudar por favor. lo estoy ejecutando de la siguiente manera, basandome en una respuesta que encontre igual aqui en el foro.

```
    wsRutas.UltimaPos ws = new wsRutas.UltimaPos();
    ws.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    ws.PreAuthenticate = true;
    ws.ultima("user", "pass"); // al llegar a este punto me sale un mesaje que dice la respuesta no es codigo XML correcto
```

cuando yo ejecuto el metodo me sale un json asi

```
 {"Geocercas":[{"Description":" Eco 79087 WM-47 53357","Latitude":19.1513000000,"Longitude":-96.1736000000,"Speed":45.62,"UtcTimeCorrected":"2018-03-08T09:20:50","Identifier":"53357"},{"Description":" Eco 93493 WR93 53283","Latitude":19.1684093652,"Longitude":-96.1298141162,"Speed":42.01,"UtcTimeCorrected":"2017-08-15T13:49:01","Identifier":"53283"}
```

cuando llega al punto donde ejecuto el metodo y le paso el usuario y password pueda yo obtener el resultado

Comment: doy por valido que el web reference esta actualizado para la url del servicio que utilizas y que se trata de un asmx, no? o es un servicio de WCF?

Comment: si pasas las credenciales usando ws.Credentials, porque depsues tienes que ponerlas en el metodo del servicio "ultima()" ?

Comment: es un servicio asmx

Comment: pero porque pasas usuario y password en el metodo? en lugar de hacerlo solo con las Credentials

Comment: Lo que pasa es que tiene usuario y clave para poder acceder a el

Comment: Me ayude de esta otra pregunta mira: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74358/c%C3%B3mo-consumo-este-web-service

Comment: Antes de esta no habia podido acceder al metodo

Comment: pero entonces no entiendo el problema, el servicio debe retornar algo ? porque en el codigo que publicas no veo que asignes a ninguna variable la repsuesta. O estas teniendo algun exception?

Comment: Pues es que intente regresarlo a un string y no me dejo cuando yo ejecuto el metodo me sale un json asi mira : {"Geocercas":[{"Description":" Eco 79087 WM-47 53357","Latitude":19.1513000000,"Longitude":-96.1736000000,"Speed":45.62,"UtcTimeCorrected":"2018-03-08T09:20:50","Identifier":"53357"},{"Description":" Eco 93493 WR93 53283","Latitude":19.1684093652,"Longitude":-96.1298141162,"Speed":42.01,"UtcTimeCorrected":"2017-08-15T13:49:01","Identifier":"53283"},

Comment: no se que hacer para que cuando llega al punto donde ejecuto el metodo y le paso el usuario y password pueda yo obtener el resultado, la vdd es la primera vez que ejecuto un servicio asi y no tengo idea de que hacer =(

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias Leandro Tuttini, ya me salio creo que ahora si ya podre terminar lo que me solicitaron, de verdad que te estoy muy agradecida y muchas gracias por tu paciencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el resultado es un json tienes que parsearlo usando la libreria json.net, la agregas por nuget a tu proyecto

[Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

entonces despues tienes que usar la pagina

http://json2csharp.com/

para obtener la clase que mapea con el json que tienes, podria ser algo como esto

```
public class Geocerca
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Speed { get; set; }
    public DateTime UtcTimeCorrected { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Geocerca> Geocercas { get; set; }
}
```

entonces usarias

```
wsRutas.UltimaPos ws = new wsRutas.UltimaPos();

string jsonResult = ws.ultima("user", "pass");

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonResult );
```

asi tendras los datos en una instancia de clase

Comment: muchas gracias por tu apoyo y sobretodo por tu paciencia, pero si el web service tiene el usuario y password como lo mando ?

Comment: no lo envias como parametro del metodo ? entendi que el metodo ultima() tienes los parametros para enviar la autenticacion

Comment: ok voy a intentarlo y lo comento mil gracias

Comment: que yo sepa no es necesario descargar una librería para hacer el parse de un json, existe una clase llamada `JavaScriptSerializer` que tiene las herramientas para hacer eso, pero básicamente es el mismo procedimiento, generas una clase con la estructura de los objetos recibidos en json y luego la usas para deserializar

Comment: @LPZadkiel la libreria json.net es mas performante que JavaScriptSerializer es por eso que se recomienda, es mas si usas .net core ya la incorpora como parte del framework